# drag and drop of multiple html elements to create a html page template

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, css, html

I want to create a template design using drag and drop of multiple html elements images just like in http://www.weebly.com . Please help me out by giving any best example script which is mostly similar to weebly i am in very much need of this kind script

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you want a site with this functionality 
or just want to design a simple page with that

you can try 
[wysiwyg editor](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=how%20to%20define%20html5%20elements%20in%20ie&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla%3aen-US%3aofficial&client=firefox-a&channel=fflb#hl=en&client=firefox-a&rls=org.mozilla%3aen-US%3aofficial&channel=fflb&q=wysiwyg%20editor&spell=1&sa=X&ei=eKAsUdK0AsP7rAeRyIDwDg&ved=0CCsQBSgA&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_qf.&bvm=bv.42965579,d.bmk&fp=8d6f5005fe1a0333&biw=1024&bih=651)

or some more [online drag and drop website builder](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=how%20to%20define%20html5%20elements%20in%20ie&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla%3aen-US%3aofficial&client=firefox-a&channel=fflb#hl=en&client=firefox-a&rls=org.mozilla%3aen-US%3aofficial&channel=fflb&sclient=psy-ab&q=online%20drag%20and%20drop%20website%20builder&oq=online%20drag%20and%20drop%20&gs_l=serp.3.1.0l2j0i30l2.44381.52116.8.54082.21.14.0.7.7.7.1883.12307.0j1j2j1j1j1j4j2j2.14.0.les;..0.0...1c.1.4.psy-ab.e8uKm66Cxgg&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_qf.&bvm=bv.42965579,d.bmk&fp=8d6f5005fe1a0333&biw=1024&bih=651) 
or

```
if(you want to make this){
    stop DayDreaming();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

jQuery UI makes this fairly simple. Give the draggable/droppable plugin a try: http://jqueryui.com/droppable/

Answer (score 1):

There is no such Drag and Drop facility like Weebly on the market. That's how Weebly makes them competitive. It's something that you have to develop your own from scratch.

You need jQuery UI, just to do Drag and Drop. But this is still basic. You need to write custom Javascript on top of jQuery UI to manipulate DOM elements.

Answer (score 0):

To experiment with drag and drop you can start off with HTML5.

It has drag and drop feature and you can make use of JavaScript to handle drag events. It is definitely the easy and best solution. Create widgets and then drop them in the target area where you want to place them, finally you will have a web template.

You are good to go!